# Proving $(p \land \lnot q) \rightarrow p$ is a tautology using logical equivalences

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

I'm very new to discrete math and propositional calculus. 
I keep getting lost trying to prove the following propositional formula is a tautology using equivalencies.

$$(p \land \lnot q) \rightarrow p$$

**Edit**: I solved it; see my answer below.

Comment: Start with $(p \land \lnot q) \to p \equiv \lnot(p \land \lnot q) \lor p$.  ($a \to b \equiv \lnot a \lor b$).  Then use DeMorgan's Law $\lnot(a\land b) \equiv \lnot a \lor \lnot b$ on the right hand side above.  Show your use of these hints, and I'll answer more fully.

Comment: currently what i got from that is $\lnot (p \land \lnot q) \lor p$, following that i got $(\lnot p \lor q) \lor p$, which then, if my thinking is correct, $q \lor (\lnot p \lor p)$ -> $q \lor T$, therefore, T

Comment: You did it, @Nikki!

Comment: Thank you! @amWhy

Comment: And now that you've done it, write it up, and post it as an answer.

Comment: Indeed, Nikki, write up all the work, and post it as an answer!

Answer (score 7):

Figured it out with amWhy's help.

$(p \land \lnot q) \rightarrow p \equiv \lnot (p \land \lnot  q) \lor p $,

As such, $\lnot (p \land \lnot q) \lor p$

Then, we use DeMorgan's law to get $(\lnot p \lor q) \lor p$,

Then, using association, $q \lor (\lnot p \lor p) $,

$q \lor T $,

T

Therefore, $(p \land \lnot q) \rightarrow p$ is a Tautology.

Comment: Very nicely written, Nikki!